# Vue v2 and v3 are different in "updated" event lifecycle of component

Tags: vuejs2, vuejs3

I have the two example of code. Both are the same. The first for Vue v2, and the second for Vue v3. This example should demonstrate emitting "update" event lifecycle of component when I type into text input and then Vue template is re-rendering. But in example for Vue v2 it's not works as I expect.

**My code example:**

```js
// components/HelloWorld.vue

<template>
  <button type="button" @click="fn($event, 'click')">HelloWorld</button>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ["fn"],
  updated() {
    console.log("HelloWorld UPDATED");
  },
};
</script>
```

```js
// App.vue

<template>
  <div>
    <input type="text" v-model="text" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <HelloWorld :fn="fn()" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import HelloWorld from "./components/HelloWorld.vue";

export default {
  components: {
    HelloWorld,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      text: "",
    };
  },
  methods: {
    fn() {
      return (a, b) => console.log(a, b);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

And I have made two sandbox example for fast touch: for [Vue v2](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue2-reactivity-u7mowj) and [Vue v3](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue3-reactivity-76ow0i).

Using Vue v3 example I type and see in the console output "HelloWorld UPDATED", because of prop `fn` of `HelloWorld` component a new every re-render.

But using Vue v2 example I type and **see nothing** in the console output.

Code example is the same. Reactivity is working in both examples, but "updated" event doesn't trigger for Vue v2. Why?

Important thing in my example is that I pass data from parent to child component and child component should re-render when its props has been changed (look at `fn()` method in `App.vue`, it return a new function every call).

Comment: Because Vue 2 has not same futures as Vue 3.

Comment: @mises, these expression is allows according to documentation. It should works, isn't? Could you please explain what you mean "futures"? What happens in my examples?

Comment: I don't know, I never used Vue 2 all I know is Vue 3 has more futures than Vue 2.

Comment: @tao, Thanks, I fixed my code example for Vue v2, but it doesn't change anything (parameters there was no matter at all). And I don't confused by an anonymous function, because it's important thing in my example, I know that they are not the same (please, read the last paragraph of my question).

Comment: Vue components re-render only when something in the template is changed. If a prop is changed but this prop is not used in the template - there is absolutely no reason for Vue to re-render the component.

Comment: @IVOGELOV, do you mean that `fn` prop in `@click` is not part of template for Vue v2, but part of template of Vue v3? However, event handler are changing every re-render and `fn` are changing too. That function is not the same every re-render and `updated()` event of lifecycle doesn't fire for Vue v2, but fire for Vue v3. Why?

Comment: Vue2 does a diff on the results of running `fn()` and doesn't update the child component because nothing changed. Everybody knows there are changes between Vue2 and Vue3 how they render and how they work internally. Why do you think that is a problem? I mean, what is your problem, the one you're trying to solve?

Comment: @tao, The `fn()` function is recreated every time I type something into the input field. You can verify this by:

`fn() { console.log("new fn()"); const d = new Date().toString(); return (a, b) => console.log(d); }`, then just click on "HelloWorld" button after typing.

And when a new function is generated, the Vue v2 "HelloWorld" component should trigger the `updated()` lifecycle event, shouldn't it?

I don't have any problem, I just want to understand core different without reading source code of two version of Vue.

Comment: @tao, could you please explain your "everybody knows there are changes between Vue2 and Vue3"? What changes?

Comment: [These](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/) changes. Please read [How much effort](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users).

Comment: @tao, could you please give me certain link about comparing props behavior? Because you post all migration guide. It's like say someone to go googling. Or, may be, if you know answer and know "how much effort" then just post its?

Comment: There is no such link. Vue3 is a complete rewrite of Vue2. If you're curious about implementation details, you're free to dive into their source code, it's open source. But I'd say this has to do more with change detection (reactivity) and DOM diffing  than with prop handling. What i can tell you for certain is that, historically, passing functions as props has been discouraged in Vue, mostly due to edge cases not working as expected due to change of context.

Comment: @tao, where I can read about recommendation for `v-bind`?

Comment: Search for *"why is passing callbacks as props considered an anti-pattern in Vue"*. It's not an official recommendation, as it's opinionated. Its relevance depends on app scale, scope, development lifecycle, team size and skill level,  and many others. As a side note, keep in mind questions inviting open ended discussions are considered *"off-topic"* on [so]. And so is asking multiple questions in a single one or in another questions' comments.